# How to return JSON from a View Component?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am trying to move controller logic into a view component class, but the controller only returns JSON, for a client side widget that is the UI of my view component. This is the core controller code where the problem is:

```
public IActionResult TreeData(string dir = "")
{
    var browsingRoot = Path.Combine(_config.BaseDir, dir);
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    nodes.AddRange(RecurseDirectory(browsingRoot));
    return Json(nodes);
}
```

This is fine in the controller, but the `ViewComponent` derived class doesn't like the `Json` return method. All examples I see use `return View(*<something>*)`.

View components are not supposed to return entire responses, so I would imagine it should rather have a `Content` return method to return pure HTML at least.

Comment: docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components

Comment: Try adding some more details about how you intend to use the component in the view. would help in providing an answer.

Comment: Why do you need to return json from your component? that's not components were designed for. you need to return view (with optional model) from it. please provide your view too, probably html generation in viewcomponent could help (s you mentioned in question, you can return pure html from InvokeAsync, but will it help you?)

Comment: @ingvar If my component's view comprises a Bootstrap plugin, and that plugin needed Json to initialize. That was before, and now the question is strictly academic. It is possible, with a `ContentViewComponentResult`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it can be done by returning content, not a view:

```
public IActionResult TreeData(string dir = "")
{
    var browsingRoot = Path.Combine(_config.BaseDir, dir);
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();
    nodes.AddRange(RecurseDirectory(browsingRoot));
    return new ContentViewComponentResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nodes));
}
```

Comment: This code gives me an error saying `Cannot implicitly convert type [...]ContentViewComponentResult to [...]IActionResult`